# Extracting Functions

Tags: python, extract

I have written a simple program that calculates the perfect squares up to a given number. My code is:

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""

def main():
   """Even the main function needs a docstring to keep pylint happy"""
   upper_bound = None
   while upper_bound is None:
       line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
       if line.isnumeric():
           upper_bound = int(line)
       else:
           print("You must enter a positive number.")

   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       for candidate in range(1, num):
           if candidate * candidate == num:
               squares.append(num)

   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ".format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print(square, end=' ')
   print()
```

I am trying to extract my block of code into several functions, I have come up with what I thought was a possible solution but unfortunately I could not get it to run as it gave me an error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`. I can't seem to find the source of this issue and I was wondering if my solution is just bad and if so what would be a better one?

My attempt

```
   """Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""

  def read_bound():
   """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
      If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
      the function issues an error message and retries
      repeatedly"""


   line = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
   if line.isnumeric() and int(line) >= 0:
       upper_bound = int(line)
   else:
       print("You must enter a positive number.")



  def is_perfect_square(num):
   """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
     for num in range( 2, upper_bound + 1):
         for candidate in range(1, num):
             if candidate * candidate == num:
                 return True



   def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
   """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""


   print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
   for square in squares:
       print(square, end= ' ')



  def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
       if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)


  main()
```

Comment: hint: You missed the while loop in original code `while upper_bound is None:`

Comment: I originally had that included but took it out to see if it fixed the error I was getting but sadly that was not the problem so now I am looking for another solution

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a lot bug! I guess you use python 3.x! I have rewrite some of your code with python 2.7! just post the code as below! If you can't run it, just let me know!

```
"""Print all the perfect squares from zero up to a given maximum."""
def read_bound():
    """Reads the upper bound from the standard input (keyboard).
       If the user enters something that is not a positive integer
       the function issues an error message and retries
       repeatedly"""

    while True:
      try:
          upper_bound = int(input("Enter the upper bound: "))
      except Exception:
          print("You must enter a positive number.")
      else:
          return upper_bound


def is_perfect_square(num):
    """Return true if and only if num is a perfect square"""
    for candidate in range(1, num):
        if candidate * candidate == num:
            return True
    return False



def print_squares(upper_bound, squares):
    """Print a given list of all the squares up to a given upper bound"""
    print("The perfect squares up to {} are: ". format(upper_bound))
    for square in squares:
        print square, ' '


def main():
   """Calling the functions"""
   upper_bound = read_bound()
   squares = []
   for num in range(2, upper_bound + 1):
        if is_perfect_square(num):
           squares.append(num)

   print_squares(upper_bound, squares)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, your code runs but instead of printing only the perfect squares, it prints every single number from 2 to `upper_bound`.

Comment: I can't believe your perfect square have double loop! so your can't get it ! I have already update the answer! you can try again!

Comment: Another problem, when I test your code with a negative `upper_bound`, it does not print `You must enter a positive number.`, Can you please fix this as well?

Comment: Because python3.x have some diff between python2.x raw_input! so we need to do covert inside the try ~ catch block! I have already fixed that bug!

Comment: We'll I am literally running your code right now and its not printing `You must enter a positive number.` when I test it with negative values for `upper_bound`. Could you check again ?

Comment: oh，you can see i used raise instead of print ！

Comment: You may want to prompt user input the right thing instead raise a exception. this will be work as your expect!